# problems white page with phonegap app in android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I develop an android app in phonegap
but when I open the app in succession then app opens and shows a blank white page?!

I do the follwoing: open, close(with backbutton),open,close then app open with blank page?!

logcat :

```
07-03 15:10:23.894: D/Config(11923): Unlimited access to network resources
07-03 15:10:23.904: I/CordovaLog(11923): Found start page location: index.html
07-03 15:10:23.904: I/CordovaLog(11923): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
07-03 15:10:23.904: D/CordovaActivity(11923): CordovaActivity.onCreate()
07-03 15:10:23.914: D/CordovaWebView(11923): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: samsung
07-03 15:10:23.914: D/JsMessageQueue(11923): Set native->JS mode to 2
07-03 15:10:23.914: D/CordovaActivity(11923): CordovaActivity.init()
07-03 15:10:23.924: D/CordovaWebView(11923): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
07-03 15:10:23.924: D/PluginManager(11923): init()
07-03 15:10:23.924: D/CordovaWebView(11923): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-03 15:10:23.934: D/Config(11923): Unlimited access to network resources
07-03 15:10:23.934: I/CordovaLog(11923): Found start page location: index.html
07-03 15:10:23.934: I/CordovaLog(11923): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
07-03 15:10:23.934: D/CordovaActivity(11923): Resuming the App
07-03 15:10:23.934: D/CordovaActivity(11923): CB-3064: The errorUrl is null
07-03 15:10:23.934: D/SecWifiDisplayUtil(11923): Metadata value : SecSettings2
07-03 15:10:23.934: D/ViewRootImpl(11923): #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{5319767 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
07-03 15:10:23.964: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(11923): Ignore this event
07-03 15:10:24.004: D/ViewRootImpl(11923): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 0) or=1
07-03 15:10:24.004: D/CordovaActivity(11923): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
07-03 15:10:24.014: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(11923): Ignore this event
07-03 15:10:24.014: I/Timeline(11923): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1404550 time:256529963
07-03 15:10:24.014: W/cr_BindingManager(11923): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 11923
07-03 15:10:24.184: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(11923): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/cordova_plugins.js
07-03 15:10:24.184: D/CordovaLog(11923): file:///android_asset/www/js/custom.js: Line 77 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined
07-03 15:10:24.184: I/chromium(11923): [INFO:CONSOLE(77)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/custom.js (77)
07-03 15:10:24.254: D/CordovaNetworkManager(11923): Connection Type: none
07-03 15:10:24.254: D/CordovaNetworkManager(11923): Connection Type: none
07-03 15:10:24.254: D/CordovaActivity(11923): onMessage(networkconnection,none)
07-03 15:10:24.254: D/CordovaActivity(11923): onMessage(spinner,stop)
07-03 15:10:24.334: D/CordovaWebViewClient(11923): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
07-03 15:10:24.334: D/CordovaActivity(11923): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
07-03 15:10:39.174: D/CordovaActivity(11923): Paused the application!
07-03 15:10:39.174: D/CordovaWebView(11923): Handle the pause
07-03 15:10:39.194: V/ActivityThread(11923): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{6130f7b token=android.os.BinderProxy@1404550 {da.com.ir/da.com.ir.Main}} show : true
```

Comment: `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/custom.js (77)` What do you have at line 77 of custom.js?

Comment: line 77 :    return ( (navigator.network.connection.type === "none" || navigator.network.connection.type === null || 
          navigator.network.connection.type === "unknown" ) ? false : true );

Comment: are you waiting for the `deviceready` to check the connection? if you do, maybe the error comes from what there is in the line just before: `Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/cordova_plugins.js`?

Comment: yes wait.  i use document.addEventListener("deviceready", TabHome($("#Home")), false);